# Modelling indexable types in UML class diagramm

Tags: typescript, uml

I have a problem modelling indexable types in an uml class diagramm.
Indexable types are used for describing dictionaries.

Following examples illustrates my problem:
Given the following JSON:

```
{
   "hero1": {
     "f": "fast",
     "c": "clever",
     "g": "good"
   },
   "hero2": {
     "e": "evil"
   },
   "hero3": {}
}
```

As you can see there is a Hero Object which contains key-value pairs of powers.
Each power has a key e.g. "f" and a value e.g. "fast".

Modelling it in UML I can something like that:
[image]

My problem is at the ... part because lets imagine there are thousands of key-value pairs, creating a class for each of them doesn't seem right.

In TypeScript I would program it like that:

```
interface PowerObject {
    [powercode: string]: string
}
```

Im not sure if I should just describe it as a Hero to PowerObject relationship with an 0..* relationship.

Edit: I think the problem differs from the linked one, based on describing the relationship between an unknown set of "classes", which structure is already known beforehand. However integrating a class into another one does make sense and was very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modelling types with UML based on associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812190/modelling-types-with-uml-based-on-associative-arrays)

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a "qualifier" on an association. Have you read about those yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that your models are useful/helpful. They confuse values with properties.

It seems that your `Hero` class has a collection-valued `powers` property where power values are just enumeration values from a `PowerEnum` = {f: "fast", c: "clever", g: "good", ...}

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answers and comments. 
Based on the first comment I can better illustrate that the PowerObject is in the Hero Object.

However a sub problem does still consist. And this is to visualize the "powers".
E.g. a PowerObject can contain zero,one or multiple values of powers like (fast | clever | good | evil | .... ).

Because the list of powers can be unlimited and is just a string i'm not quite sure if I have illustrated it in the correct way.

[image]